# Hierarchical data template trigger selected item property

Tags: wpf, triggers, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate, application-resource

I have created a static application resource for my `TreeView` style. I have a custom type as the hierarchical data template type, let's call it Foobar. The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` items source is bound to the Foobar's FooCollection.

The custom object binding is not an issue. Problem is I want to change style of the selected `TreeViewItem` using triggers. The trigger for property `IsMouseOver` trigger as it should. But I cannot find anywhere to trigger the property `IsSelected` in my `HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers`?

```
<Style TargetType="TreeView" x:Key="TreeView">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"/>

    <Style.Resources>

        <!--Foobar tree view items-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type f:Foobar}" ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection}">

            <TextBlock Name="tbbName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#7FFFFFFF" FontSize="16"/>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="tbbName" Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="#7FFFFFFF" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="tbbName" Property="Foreground" Value="#AFFFFFFF"/>
                </Trigger>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Does `f:foobar` derive from an `UIElement` with a `IsSelected` `Property` (e.g. like `TreeViewItem`)? The `IsMouseOver` is there because it's a common `Property` from `UIElement`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is binding the `IsSelected`-property from `TreeViewItem` to a corresponding property in `Foobar`

```
class Foobar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if(_isSelected == value)
                return;
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            ...
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

then you can use a `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Setters>
        ...
    </DataTrigger.Setters>
</DataTrigger>
```